# My One Class Autoencoder's ROC Curve Appears to be Inverted

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoder, roc, auc, one-class-classification

I am training a One Class Autoencoder on 50,000 benign samples. Then, when testing the model, I am giving it 10,000 benign samples and 10,000 anomolies. The resulting F1 and Recall score of the model is 0.974 ad 0.992, respectively. It is able to classify that there are 9600 anomolies and 10,400 benign samples (so not perfect, but performs really well). However, when I go to plot the ROC curve and calculate the AUC, I am met with a value of 0.005.

How could this be possible?

I am using sklearns roc_curve() function to calculate the fpr and tpr so I can plot the curve, and then the auc() function to get the numerical value.

I do not see how it is possible that my model can perform so well, but somehow still have such a low AUC. If anyone has any tips, they would be greatly appreciated. I have attached my autoencoder model below: Feel free to ask for any more information

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model 
from keras import regularizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, f1_score, recall_score
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np

class Autoencoder:
  
  def __init__(self, encoding_dim=64, activity_regularizer=10e-6):
    self.encoding_dim = encoding_dim
    self.activity_regularizer = activity_regularizer
    self.autoencoder = None
    self.threshold = None
    
  def fit(self, x_train, x_valid, epochs=50, batch_size=256, earlystop_patience=10):
    # Input Shape
    input_dim = x_train.shape[1]

    # Input Layer
    input_layer = Input(shape = (input_dim,))

    # Encoder Layers
    hidden_layer1 = Dense(512, activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(self.activity_regularizer))(input_layer)
    hidden_layer1 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden_layer1)

    hidden_layer2 = Dense(256, activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(self.activity_regularizer))(hidden_layer1)
    hidden_layer2 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden_layer2)

    encoded = Dense(self.encoding_dim, activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(self.activity_regularizer))(hidden_layer2)

    # Decoder Layers
    hidden_layer4 = Dense(256, activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(self.activity_regularizer))(encoded)
    hidden_layer4 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden_layer4)

    hidden_layer5 = Dense(512, activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(self.activity_regularizer))(hidden_layer4)
    hidden_layer5 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden_layer5)

    decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer5)

    # Define autoencoder
    self.autoencoder = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = decoded)

    # Compile Autoencoder
    self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

    # Early stopping
    earlystop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=earlystop_patience, verbose=1, mode='min')

    # Train
    self.autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, validation_data = (x_valid, x_valid), callbacks=[earlystop_callback])

  def evaluate(self, x_test, true):
    pred = self.autoencoder.predict(x_test)

    # Reconstruction Error
    mse = np.mean(np.power(x_test - pred, 2), axis = 1)
    np.savetxt('mse.csv', mse, delimiter=',')
    # Threshold Calculation
    self.threshold = np.mean(mse)
    print("Threshold: ")
    print(self.threshold)
    print("\n")

    # True Label Calculations for AE
    ae_test = np.where(mse <= self.threshold, 1, -1)
    anomoly_counter = 0
    normal_counter = 0
    np.savetxt('ae_test.csv', ae_test, delimiter=',')

    for val in ae_test:
      if val == -1:
        anomoly_counter += 1
      elif val == 1:
        normal_counter += 1

    # AUC Calculations
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(true, mse, pos_label=1)
    auc_num = auc(fpr, tpr)


    # F1 Score
    f1 = f1_score(true, ae_test)


    # Recall Score
    recall = recall_score(true, ae_test)

    print('AUC: {:.3f}'.format(auc_num))       
    print('Recall: {:.3f}'.format(recall))
    print('F1 Score: {:.3f}'.format(f1))
    print('Anomaly: {:.3f}'.format(anomoly_counter))
    print('Positive Class: {:.3f}'.format(normal_counter))

    return fpr, tpr

  def save_model(self, model_file):
    with open(model_file, 'wb') as file:
      pickle.dump(self, file)
```

I compared the predicted binary values to the actual values and they do align. So, all the values that are predicted as an inlier (1) are actually inliers and the values predicted as anomalies (-1) are actually anomalies.

Additionally, I am training an OCSVM on the same data and getting an AUC of 0.997 with reflective f1 and recall scores.

I am almost 100% certain that the ROC is just somehow inverted for the AE, but I do not how to prove it or uninvert it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37G8t.png)

ROC CURVE:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RSJSTtHW46ZnNRYSInCGOP9sScPRe71j/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I think you are inverting the two classes: what happens if you do `roc_curve(true, mse, pos_label=-1)`?

Comment: The AUC goes to 0.996! Is that the case, that the two classes were just inverted?

Comment: I guess so, can you attach a plot of the ROC? I mean the one with very low AUC

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RSJSTtHW46ZnNRYSInCGOP9sScPRe71j/view?usp=share_link

Here you are.

Comment: Yeah, it's due to inverted classes: consider it depends on what you assume to be normal behavior, for example I noticed that you consider anomalies to be below the threshold (`mse <= self.threshold`), one can also do the opposite (`mse > threshold`). (a part from this, consider adding the image in the question's description for others too.)